# Acer C720 connects to wireless network, but can't load webpages

Tags: wireless, acer

I am posting this question and answer from
[link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2242235)
because I faced the same problem,
and the solution in that post was helpful to me.

Question from the link:

> I have an Acer C720 Chromebook, running a dual boot of Chrome OS and
>   Ubuntu 14.04.
>
> When using Chrome OS, I can connect to and use private and public
>   wireless networks with no problems. With Ubuntu, I can also connect to
>   all networks, but with the vast majority of networks I have tried, I
>   cannot use the Internet; the standard 'Server Not Found' screen
>   appears when trying to load up web pages, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I am paraphrasing the solution which is found in the link:

1. Delete `/etc/resolv.conf`

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge resolvconf
   ```
2. Restart the computer
3. Now the wireless Internet works. We can rebuild the file

   ```
   sudo apt-get install resolvconf
   ```